# sending and receiving events in Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, events

I'm used to C++/Qt's concept of signals (emit/listen) and now I'm doing a project in Java which requires some sort of data sending/receiving mechanism.

My needs are:

- Emit an event (with some data) and let all threads listen/catch it.
- Obviously, given the previous requirement, being able to listen/catch signals with attached data.

Is this possible in Java, and how? (I'll appreciate a small compilable example/link)

Comment: Why can't you use observer design pattern? There may be specific requirements in you app that does not comply with observer design pattern, but unless I am aware of all the requirements, I cannot be very sure

Comment: @user3790568 Because I want to broadcast signals, which doesn't quite fit in the observer pattern (unless I do some really hacky thing, which I'd rather avoid)

Comment: Perhaps you can use wait() on an idling thread to wait for a notifyAll()? That way you can check if anything changed and then emit an event if appropriate. Not sure if this qualifies as "hacky" to you.

Answer (score 1):

Java by default doesn't have a simple event handling mechanism such as .Net's events or Qt's Signals and Slots. It does have the notion of Listeners in various java GUI frameworks but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

You should consider a pub-sub library like [Google Guava's EventBus framework](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained).

If you don't want to use a third party lib then I suggest you start looking into using one of the sub-classes of `BlockingQueue`. See the [FileCrawler example](http://cs.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~nicolasw/Docencia/PCeJ/jcip.pdf#page=68) from page 62 of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) to see how to use a BlockingQueue to send events/data to worker threads.

If you're looking for a more complicated solution for message/event notifications across the process boundary or the local machine boundary then you may want to look into:

- [RabbitMq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html)
- Redis
- JMS

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will match your exact query but have you tried CountDownLatch or CyclicBarrier?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: Those are not quite what I'm looking for. Both methods require for "waiting" at some point (some operation to be finished or threads to be syncronized) while what I'm looking for is just a event-based solution (so that I can emit/listen for signals at any point)